# Query in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

With this query

```
SELECT Year, Month,  Customer, Cod_user, Int(Sum(hours)) AS hours
FROM T_Att
GROUP BY Year, Mounth, Customer, Cod_user
HAVING (((Year)="2016") AND ((Month)="03") AND ((Customer)="CA"));
```

I get the following result

[image]

If you want to add the **global sum (sum)** and a **key**, what needs to change?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I haven't tested you should be able to just add another field:

This will add all hours for all years, months and customers.

```
SELECT      Year, 
            Month,  
            Customer, 
            Cod_user, 
            Int(Sum(hours)) AS lhours,
            (
             SELECT SUM(hours)
             FROM T_Att
            ) AS GlobalTotal
FROM        T_Att
GROUP BY    Year, Month, Customer, Cod_user
HAVING      (((Year)="2016") AND ((Month)="03") AND ((Customer)="CA"));
```

To keep the GlobalTotal to March 2016 use:

```
SELECT      Year, 
            Month,  
            Customer, 
            Cod_user, 
            Int(Sum(hours)) AS lhours,
            (
             SELECT SUM(hours)
             FROM T_Att
             WHERE Year = T1.Year AND Month = T1.Month
            ) AS GlobalTotal
FROM        T_Att T1
GROUP BY    Year, Month, Customer, Cod_user
HAVING      (((Year)="2016") AND ((Month)="03") AND ((Customer)="CA"));
```

Note - I've renamed `hours` to `lhours` to avoid a circular reference.  You should also consider renaming `year` and `month` as these are key words and may cause problems.
Also, `year` and `month` would be better as numbers rather than text.